# Issue with installing AEM 6

Tags: aem

I am unable to install AEM6.0 in my system through I have placed correct properties file. Please find below the errors.

```
*INFO* [qtp2067191557-43] org.apache.sling.auth.core.impl.SlingAuthenticator getAnonymousResolver: Anonymous access not allowed by configuration - requesting credentials
09.02.2015 11:54:54.749 *ERROR* [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 [1423463094744] GET /libs/granite/core/content/login.html HTTP/1.1] org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingRequestProcessorImpl service: Uncaught SlingException
org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 95 in the jsp file: /libs/granite/core/components/login/login.jsp
The type java.lang.CharSequence cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
92:             ? request.getParameter(PARAM_NAME_REASON)
93:             : "";
94: 
95:     if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(reason)) {
96:         if (validReasons.containsKey(reason)) {
97:             reason = validReasons.get(reason);
98:         } else {


An error occurred at line: 95 in the jsp file: /libs/granite/core/components/login/login.jsp
The method isEmpty(CharSequence) in the type StringUtils is not applicable for the arguments (String)
92:             ? request.getParameter(PARAM_NAME_REASON)
93:             : "";
94: 
95:     if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(reason)) {
96:         if (validReasons.containsKey(reason)) {
97:             reason = validReasons.get(reason);
98:         } else {

    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:92)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:330)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:421)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:312)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:290)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:277)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:501)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.prepareServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:427)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:486)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:449)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.JspScriptEngineFactory.callJsp(JspScriptEngineFactory.java:265)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.JspScriptEngineFactory.access$100(JspScriptEngineFactory.java:87)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.JspScriptEngineFactory$JspScriptEngine.eval(JspScriptEngineFactory.java:465)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.DefaultSlingScript.call(DefaultSlingScript.java:361)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.DefaultSlingScript.eval(DefaultSlingScript.java:171)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.DefaultSlingScript.service(DefaultSlingScript.java:463)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.request.RequestData.service(RequestData.java:511)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.SlingComponentFilterChain.render(SlingComponentFilterChain.java:45)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:64)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMDebugFilter.doFilter(WCMDebugFilter.java:146)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMComponentFilter.filterRootInclude(WCMComponentFilter.java:357)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMComponentFilter.doFilter(WCMComponentFilter.java:166)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at com.day.cq.personalization.impl.TargetComponentFilter.doFilter(TargetComponentFilter.java:96)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingRequestProcessorImpl.processComponent(SlingRequestProcessorImpl.java:284)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.RequestSlingFilterChain.render(RequestSlingFilterChain.java:49)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:64)
    at com.adobe.granite.requests.logging.impl.RequestLoggerImpl.doFilter(RequestLoggerImpl.java:137)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at com.adobe.cq.social.commons.security.SaferSlingPostServlet.doFilter(SaferSlingPostServlet.java:121)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.AuthoringUIModeServiceImpl.doFilter(AuthoringUIModeServiceImpl.java:349)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.warp.TimeWarpFilter.doFilter(TimeWarpFilter.java:106)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.mobile.core.impl.redirect.RedirectFilter.doFilter(RedirectFilter.java:295)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.debug.RequestProgressTrackerLogFilter.doFilter(RequestProgressTrackerLogFilter.java:64)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at com.adobe.cq.social.commons.cors.CORSAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(CORSAuthenticationFilter.java:91)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.foundation.forms.impl.FormsHandlingServlet.doFilter(FormsHandlingServlet.java:251)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at com.day.cq.theme.impl.ThemeResolverFilter.doFilter(ThemeResolverFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at com.adobe.granite.optout.impl.OptOutFilter.doFilter(OptOutFilter.java:74)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMRequestFilter.doFilter(WCMRequestFilter.java:90)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at com.adobe.cq.history.impl.HistoryRequestFilter.doFilter(HistoryRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.designimporter.CanvasPageDeleteRequestFilter.doFilter(CanvasPageDeleteRequestFilter.java:88)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at org.apache.sling.rewriter.impl.RewriterFilter.doFilter(RewriterFilter.java:83)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at com.adobe.granite.httpcache.impl.InnerCacheFilter.doFilter(InnerCacheFilter.java:77)
    at com.adobe.granite.httpcache.impl.InnerCacheFilter.doFilter(InnerCacheFilter.java:56)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at org.apache.sling.i18n.impl.I18NFilter.doFilter(I18NFilter.java:128)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at com.adobe.cq.dam.s7imaging.impl.auth.MemoryTokenAuthHandler.doFilter(MemoryTokenAuthHandler.java:156)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at org.apache.sling.bgservlets.impl.BackgroundServletStarterFilter.doFilter(BackgroundServletStarterFilter.java:135)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at com.adobe.granite.resourceresolverhelper.impl.ResourceResolverHelperImpl.doFilter(ResourceResolverHelperImpl.java:81)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingRequestProcessorImpl.doProcessRequest(SlingRequestProcessorImpl.java:153)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingMainServlet.service(SlingMainServlet.java:205)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:339)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:300)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.ServletPipeline.handle(ServletPipeline.java:93)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:50)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:31)
    at org.apache.sling.i18n.impl.I18NFilter.doFilter(I18NFilter.java:128)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:108)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:80)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:46)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:31)
    at org.apache.felix.http.sslfilter.internal.SslFilter.doFilter(SslFilter.java:55)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:108)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:80)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:46)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:31)
    at com.adobe.granite.license.impl.LicenseCheckFilter.doFilter(LicenseCheckFilter.java:276)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:108)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:80)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:46)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:31)
    at org.apache.sling.security.impl.ReferrerFilter.doFilter(ReferrerFilter.java:290)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:108)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:80)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:46)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:31)
    at org.apache.sling.featureflags.impl.FeatureManager.doFilter(FeatureManager.java:115)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:108)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:80)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:46)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:31)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.log.RequestLoggerFilter.doFilter(RequestLoggerFilter.java:75)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:108)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:80)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:46)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:31)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.FilterPipeline.dispatch(FilterPipeline.java:76)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.Dispatcher.dispatch(Dispatcher.java:49)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.DispatcherServlet.service(DispatcherServlet.java:67)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:684)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:428)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:494)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:971)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1033)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:644)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:667)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I checked that in system console, 392 bundles in total - all 392 bundles active. It seems there is no problem with OSGI bundle. Could you please tell me what could be the issue?

Answer (score 10):

AEM 6.0 is not compatible with Java 8. Installing [AEM 6.0 SP2](http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-0/release-notes-sp2.html) should fix this issue.

Comment: I get the above error on the login page.  How do I install SP2 without being able to login?

Answer (score 1):

I have executed this java -XX:MaxPermSize=128m -Xmx384M -jar cq5-author-p4502.jar line in terminal, It is working now.

I dont understand why did not it work when I double that jar file? What could be the root cause finally? tell us if you have faced similar kind of issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For adobe CQ version 6 with JAVA 8 Windows, We faced the same issue.

1. Go ahead and uninstall the JAVA 8 updates from "programs and features" in Control panel.
2. Now ensure that you restart the windows.
3. Ensure your java version is 7 and continue starting the CQ app.

(Note setting `JAVA_PATH` or `CLASS_PATH` to jdk 7 doesnt solve the issue.)

Answer (score 0):

I've just found a fix for this that worked for me. I was having the same error using jdk1.7.0_80.jdk.

I was looking for ways to switch Java easily and found this: http://www.jayway.com/2014/01/15/how-to-switch-jdk-version-on-mac-os-x-maverick/

So I added this to my bash profile:

```
function setjdk() {
  if [ $# -ne 0 ]; then
   removeFromPath '/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Home/bin'
   if [ -n "${JAVA_HOME+x}" ]; then
    removeFromPath $JAVA_HOME
   fi
   export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v $@`
   export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
  fi
}
function removeFromPath() {
  export PATH=$(echo $PATH | sed -E -e "s;:$1;;" -e "s;$1:?;;")
}
setjdk 1.7
```

Now my version of CQ5 works with Java 1.6. 1.7 and 1.8.

So it must have been something to do with multiple versions of Java in the PATH conflicting.