# Unable to open localhost for AEM in browser

Tags: aem

Am trying to install AEM. I can open the quick start where it loads up first. However, when it comes to opening the same in browser(https://localhost:8080) it gives me an error "Unable to compile class for JSP". Please find the complete error:

```
Unable to compile class for JSP: An error occurred at line: 95 in the jsp
file: /libs/granite/core/components/login/login.jsp 
The type java.lang.CharSequence cannot be resolved.
It is indirectly referenced from required .class files 
92: ?request.getParameter(PARAM_NAME_REASON)
93: : "";
94:
95: if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(reason)) {
96: if (validReasons.containsKey(reason)) {
97: reason = validReasons.get(reason);
98: } else { 
An error occurred at line: 95 in the jsp file: 
/libs/granite/core/components/login/login.jsp
The method isEmpty(CharSequence) in the type StringUtils is not applicable for the arguments (String)
92: ? request.getParameter(PARAM_NAME_REASON)
93: : "";
94:
95: if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(reason)) {
96: if (validReasons.containsKey(reason)) {
97: reason = validReasons.get(reason);
98: } else {

Cannot serve request to /libs/granite/core/content/login.html in /libs/granite/core/components/login/login.jsp
```

Please assist me on the same.

Comment: Which version of Java and AEM are you using?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Issue with installing AEM 6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28404003/issue-with-installing-aem-6)
Please check out the answers posted there for a solution. Voting to close this question as a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

This error usually occurs when you try to run AEM with a higher version of JDK than what it supports (most commonly running your vanilla AEM 6.0 with Java 8).

If that is the case, either revert to JDK7 or install Service Pack 2 for AEM 6.0 which supports JDK 8.

For steps on installing the service pack to fix this issue refer [this thread](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1825673) in Adobe Forums.